# Difference between Svelte REPL and local output

Tags: javascript, node.js, svelte

TL;DR: Online REPL (Svelte 1.9.1) works, but local is broken.  The question: **what am I doing wrong, locally?**

The following code works in [this REPL](https://svelte.technology/repl/?version=1.9.1&gist=5fb81f7b747694745332dc685a1749bc):

```
  {{grades}}<br>
  {{#each guesses as guess, i}}
      {{#each guess as slot}}
        {{slot}}
      {{/each}}
        =
      {{ grades[i] }}
  {{/each}}


<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        guesses: [
          [0, 1, 1, 3, 6],
        ],
        grades: [
          [1, 2, 2],
        ],
      }
    },
  };
</script>
```

That is, it produces the output:

> 1,2,2
>
> 01136 = 1,2,2

However, locally (Svelte 1.9.1 on Linux Mint 18.1, 64-bit), that exact same file produces this output:

> 1,2,2
>
> 01136 = undefined

As you can see, it accesses `grades` just fine, but not `grades[i]` within the `#each` loop.  The console reports no errors.

## One other mysterious thing

If I remove these lines:

```
      {{#each guess as slot}}
        {{slot}}
      {{/each}}
```

...then the local rendering becomes:

> 1,2,2
>
> = 1,2,2

So how does that `#each` block make `grades[i]` undefined all of the sudden...but only locally?

## Additional environment info

The local version is pulled in via the following:

`Game.js`

```
import Game from '../components/Game.html';

const GameComponent = new Game({
  target: document.querySelector('main'),
});

export default GameComponent;
```

`main.js`

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */

import Game from './js/Game';
```

`index.html`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>CheaterMind</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="colours.css">
</head>
<body>
  <main></main>
  <script src='../dist/main.js' charset='utf-8'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The setup is a copy of https://github.com/charpeni/svelte-example and I'm using `npm run build:watch`.

Comment: That's a pretty wild bug — I can't get the same result locally, are you able to create a shareable repro?

Comment: @RichHarris Sure, just a minute.  I'm never sure (with any tech) whether it's me or the tech.  :)

Comment: @RichHarris https://github.com/IBwWG/cheatermind/tree/svelte-start

Comment: Thanks. My working hypothesis at the moment is that the bug is caused by the difference between standalone mode (which the REPL uses), and shared mode (which rollup-plugin-svelte uses) — possibly a variable getting stomped somewhere. Investigating.

Comment: I think you have an out-of-date version of Svelte! Try deleting your yarn.lock file and your node_modules folder and reinstalling — that fixed it for me

Comment: @RichHarris that's totally it.  I was thrown by the fact that `svelte --version` (after the github issue about version info mismatches) reported 1.9.1.  I guess the global and the `--save-dep` version are not the same thing, and somehow the local one gets used (correctly) even though it's not what gets used when I type `svelte` at the command line in the project's directory.  Still have to get used to that in the npm ecosystem.

Comment: Although, it's interesting, running `yarn` replaced the `svelte@^1.9.0: version "1.9.0"` in `yarn.lock` with `svelte@^1.6.0, svelte@^1.9.0: version "1.9.1"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to svelte 1.9.1 *locally* with `yarn upgrade svelte`.